# T(n) = 2T(n-1) + T(n/2) + 1. $\theta (T(n)) = 2^n$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

So I need to find $f$ such that T(n) = $\theta(f)$ and **prove it by induction!**

So $f = 2^n$.
I need to show that $T(n) = O(2^n)$ and $T(n) = \Omega(2^n)$

1. $T(n) = \Omega(2^n)$. I need to show that: $T(n) \geq c_1 2^n$

$$T(n) = 2T(n-1) + T(n/2) + 1$$
$$T(n) \geq 2*c_1*2^{n-1} + 2^{n/2} + 1$$
$$T(n) \geq c_1*2^n + 2^{n/2} + 1$$
$$T(n) \geq c_12^n $$

2. $T(n) = O(2^n)$. I need to show that: $T(n) \leq c_2 2^n$

$$T(n) = 2T(n-1) + T(n/2) + 1$$
$$T(n) \leq 2*c_2*2^{n-1} + 2^{n/2} + 1$$
$$T(n) \leq c_2*2^n + 2^{n/2} + 1$$
$$T(n) \not\leq c_22^n $$
I need to make my claim stronger in order to show it  $T(n) \leq c_2 2^n - something $. But I don't know how. Any tips

Comment: Do you know that $T(n) = \theta(2^n),$ or is this just your guess?

Comment: It's my guess, since we have $2^n + log(n)$

Comment: Where does this $2^n+\log(n)$ come from?